# How to resolve a GitHub Pull Request conversation (comment thread) using GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm working on a process to migrate a repo from GitLab to GitHub.
One of the things this process needs to do is recreate Merge Requests from GitLab as Pull Requests in GitHub, along with their conversation history.

I managed to use the GitHub API to create the PR and comments from the original MR, but as some comment threads in the original MR were already resolved I wanted to use the API to mark those conversations in the PR as resolved as well, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Right now I just add a final comment to the conversation that says it it resolved, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's only available in GraphQL at this point:

https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#resolvereviewthread

The GraphQL seems straightforward but it's not. The input of that mutation requires an id of something called "review thread" but there's no such concept in the REST API. With an id of "comment" from REST API, the only way to find the corresponding "review thread" is to retrieve all the review threads and filter by the comments inside.

Answer (score 1):

With gh 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022), you now have [`gh pr lock`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_lock), but for the all conversation, not an individual comment:

```
gh pr lock --reason resolved
```

unlock will unlock a conversation if it was previously locked. Otherwise, it will do nothing.

> lock will lock a conversation if it was previously unlocked.
> You can optionally specify a reason for locking from a set of fixed reasons.
>
> - "`off_topic`",
> - "`resolved`",
> - "`spam`",
> - "`too_heated`"
>
> If the issue or pull request is already locked, `gh` will prompt you to confirm if you want to "relock" a conversation or abort the "relock" if you forgot or didn't know the conversation was already locked.
> The primary use for relocking will probably be to change the lock reason.

---

For an individual comment, you would need, first, to list all review comments on the PR to find the correct place to add your resolution comment:

```bash
gh api repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/comments
```

Once you have identified the correct comment thread, you can post a comment to it:

```bash
gh api -X POST repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/comments -F body="That conversation was resolved in the original GitLab MR." -F in_reply_to=:comment_id
```

That would not "resolve" as in [`resolveReviewThread`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#resolvereviewthread), but at least it would add a comment to the thread.

Comment: I'm confused. How do you specify which comment to lock? This seems similar to [this API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#lock-an-issue), but it only accepts an `issue_number` (which could be a PR since a PR is also an issue), but then wouldn't it lock the entire PR rather than a single conversation within the PR?

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva True, this is for the entire PR. I have edited the answer to make that clearer, as well as leaving an alternative approach for a single comment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, after doing more research I learned that not everything is available on the Rest API, so I'm considering using GraphQL in my GitHub App's code. Thanks!!!

Comment: @AlissonReinaldoSilva Good call. [Cat Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555699/cat-chen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73317004/6309) points to GraphQL indeed.